# import sql query rows into separate word tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to create in word, an alarm dictionary based on a sql server table where the alarms are defined.

The sql alarm table has columns for things like: Alarm Name, Type, Severity, Code, Additional Data, User Action, etc. Currently there are hundreds of alarms.

I need a word table for each alarm, plugging in the values from a query into the sql table.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I should add that if it is simpler to do this from say, an xml document or an excel file, it would be simple enough to adjust the sql query to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. It seemed easiest to first create an Excel spreadsheet from the query and work from there so that's what I did. Next I created the following VBA macro:

```
Sub BuildAlarmDict()

Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim exWs As Excel.Worksheet

Dim row As Integer
Dim tbl As Word.Table
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim myRng As Range

Set exWb = exApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\AlarmDictData.xls")
Set exWs = exWb.Sheets(1)

For row = exWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

    Set myRng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.Range.End, End:=Selection.Range.End)

    With myRng
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End With

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=myRng, NumRows:=6, NumColumns:=2)

    With tbl

        .AllowPageBreaks = False
        .Columns(1).Width = 122
        .Columns(2).Width = 351

        With .Rows(1)
            .Cells.Merge
            .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = 16

            With .Range
                .Bold = True
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                .Font.Size = 12
            End With
        End With

        With .Borders
            .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        End With

        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = exWs.Cells(row, 1) & " : " & exWs.Cells(row, 2)
        .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Alarm Code"
        .Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = exWs.Cells(row, 1)
        .Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Specific Problem"
        .Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = exWs.Cells(row, 2)
        .Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "Perceived Severity"
        .Cell(4, 2).Range.Text = exWs.Cells(row, 3)
        .Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = "Probable Cause"
        .Cell(5, 2).Range.Text = exWs.Cells(row, 4)
        .Cell(6, 1).Range.Text = "Additional Text"
        .Cell(6, 2).Range.Text = exWs.Cells(row, 5)
    End With
Next

exWb.Close
Set exApp = Nothing

End Sub
```